# In protractot automation - How do i click on table first row first value of column name is "job no".

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor, e2e-testing

[image]

Because i have three table structure in same page. Attaching screenshot how the page would look like.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML code.

Comment: Its a angularjs application. But this may be helpful for reference @SudharsanSelvaraj
<tr>
<th translate="" class="ng-scope">Job no</th>
<th translate="" class="ng-scope">Description</th>
<th translate="" class="ng-scope">Reference</th>
<th class="column-to-hide ng-scope" translate="">Contact</th>
<th translate="" class="ng-scope">Address line 1</th>
 <th translate="" class="ng-scope">Address line 2</th>
<th class="column-to-hide ng-scope" translate="">Status</th>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide some kind of specific selector to catch the element you want. One way to do it, in order to differentiate between the tables, is to give each one a "debugID" attribute, dummy HTML attribute with some unique name / ID. (I recommend not to use HTML ID tag as browsers are looking on them and in case they won't be unique, for example, you may get some other issues..).

Comment: No, there are no such unique id/name. Its a dynamic page where result will be based on the what we tried to search from different table.